# Unselect ListView item on Android

Tags: android, listview

My `ListView` is set to `singleChoice` mode, the item view contains a `Button`. If I select the list item, the `Button` changes to visible.

When the list item is unselected the `Button` set to gone. How can I do that?

It is similar to the change of background color.

actually, my list item contains a textView and a delete button,
the delete button are visible only  when the item is selected

Answer (score 2):

Use [`setOnItemClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) method

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        if(b.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
});
```

Comment: @iturki sorry i cant see this and   we have same answer  so finally i delete my answer

Comment: @user370305 [isShown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isShown()) is actually defined for View. And as documented `it will return True if this view and all of its ancestors are VISIBLE`. I don't know but I trust `getVisibility()`.

Comment: Yes, If you use `inShown()` only for Button then its returns the visibility of current Button View which you are referring..

Comment: @user370305 What about the `ancestors`. What does it mean??